# get value from observable to use it in component.ts - Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

During an Angular course we build kinda hotel reservation system with Angular. The application is quite simple with basic CRUD functions and each reservation has an ID, name, room number, arrival- and departure date. The data is fetched with an InMemory Web-API.

I struggle with setting the Booking ID based on the highes existing one and increment it by 1. If the latest booking (based on the creation date) has ID 111, an ID 112 should be pre-set when accessing the create view.

Since the bookings are subscribed and the subscription returns an observable, it seems I cannot simply iterate through it and assign the last id to a variable and use this one then to determine the new ID.

The create-booking.component.ts looks as follows:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Booking} from "../booking";
import {Router, ActivatedRoute} from "@angular/router";
import {BookingService} from "../booking.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-create-booking',
  templateUrl: './create-booking.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./create-booking.component.css']
})
export class CreateBookingComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private bookingService: BookingService) { }

  bookings = this.bookingService.getBookings().subscribe((result) => {
    console.log(typeof result);
    return result;
  });

//TODO Make sure latest id shows up automatically


  // @ts-ignore
  booking: Booking = {
    id: 999,
    name: "Your Name",
    roomNumber: 100,
    startDate: new Date(),
    endDate: new Date(),
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    if(this.router.url != "/createBooking"){
      var id = Number(this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id'));
      this.bookingService.getBookingById(id).subscribe((result) =>{
        this.booking = result;
      });
    }
  }

  save(): void{
    this.bookingService.addBooking(this.booking).subscribe();

    this.router.navigate(['bookings']);
  }

  dateChanged(event: Event, isStart: boolean){
    var val = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value;

    if(isStart){
      this.booking.startDate = new Date(val);
    }
    else{
      this.booking.endDate = new Date(val);
    }
  }

}
```

The booking.service.ts that includes the getBookings function includes this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Booking} from "./booking";
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from "@angular/common/http";
import {Observable} from "rxjs";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class BookingService {

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  bookingsURL: string = "/api/bookings";

  getBookings(): Observable<Booking[]>{
    var resp = this.httpClient.get<Booking[]>(this.bookingsURL);
    return resp;
  }

  getBookingById(id : number) : Observable<Booking>{
    var resp = this.httpClient.get<Booking>(`${this.bookingsURL}/${id}`);
    return resp ;
  }

  delete(booking: Booking): Observable<Booking>{
    var resp = this.httpClient.delete<Booking>(`${this.bookingsURL}/${booking.id}`)
    return resp;
  }

  addBooking(booking: Booking) : Observable<Booking> {
    var resp = this.httpClient.post<Booking>(this.bookingsURL, booking);
    return resp;
  }
}
```

I hope you can help me to sort this out. Please bear with me in case I used an incorrect thread or did anything wring - this is my first question here :)

Comment: The backend is generally responsible for generating id's. You should not need to provide an id when creating a new booking. The http endpoint responsible for creating bookings should have a way to track what the next id should be. Otherwise you can simply generate a long random string. There are libraries for generating unique ids.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I get your point but just theoretically, would it be possible to create the number by using the observable, anyhow?

Comment: Sure, just make an end point that returns the highest id and add one to it.

Comment: Your in-memory api just gets reset every time you refresh doesn't it? Can you not just store the next id in a global variable?

Comment: Thanks again for your feedback. Yes it does. Every time the app re-loads all changes will disappear, but that’s no problem. 
Can you share an example for the endpoint? 
I’ve tried it with the following but since the return was an observable with the type any, an error occurred when I was about to set it as ID: latestId = this.bookingService.getBookings().subscribe((result) => {
    len = result.length 
    return result[len - 1].id;
  });

Comment: If everything is in memory, easiest thing is to just store the next id as a global variable in a service. See Charlie V's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make a very small service that does this for you.

There will only be 1 instance of this service, because you provide it in root. Therefor you can have multiple instances of your component and still end up with unique numbers. Whenever you restart your app, the number is reset. But that is something you seem to accept for now.

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
class NewIDService {
  private newID: number = 10001;

  public getNewIDObs(): number {     
    this.newID += 1;
    return this.newID;
  }
}
```